# Why won't the bandstop filter work in this circuit?

Tags: active-filter, band-pass, cutoff-frequency

This is the EMG circuit I designed. [image: circuit]

The cut off frequency of the bandpass is 20-3k Hz. This somehow worked already. But the bandstop filter doesn't show. Why is this?

This is the freq-vout graph and the resulting figure. The same thing shows in ac sweep.

[image: graph]

What changes should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your band stop filter is made from two other filters - one high pass filter and one low pass filter.

Each of those two filters are of the lowest order possible. They are simple resistor/capacitor filters with a roll-off of 6 dB per octave or 20 dB per decade.

That means that in the stop band for each filter, the output is attenuated (reduced) by 1/2 for each doubling of frequency.

Take the low pass filter (R3 and C5). The cut-off is at 50 Hz.  With 6 dB per octave, it will reduce a 100 Hz signal to half its original intensity.

The high pass filter (C4 and R1) has a cut-off of 60 Hz. It will reduce a signal at 30 Hz to half its original intensity.

The gap between the high pass and the low pass is only 10 Hz. That's only 1/5 or 1/6 of an octave. At best, you are getting 1/5 of 6dB attenuation from your "band stop" filter. That's not enough to see in your frequency plot.

You need a better filter to remove power line hum.

Analog filters to effectively remove powerline hum must use higher order filters. Those can be quite complicated to design and build properly.

I had a look around the internet but couldn't find an example that I thought was really good.

---

A better way to deal with hum is to filter it digitally.

Many analog to digital converters (ADC) intended for the kind of work you are doing include a digital powerline hum filter that is far more effective than what you have tried to build.

If that isn't effective enough, you can apply a powerline hum filter to your data in software. Once the data is on your computer in digital form, you can do a lot of things to clean it up.

[This paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/830463v1.full) gives an example of implementing an effective powerline hum removal using MatLab. [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) gives you most of the functionality of MatLab for free, and many MatLab programs will "just work" when used with Octave.